# Set timeOut for session/transaction to DefaultMessageListenerContainer

Tags: java, performance, jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I want to receive chunk of messages from Queue within some timeLimit(Ex : 300 millisec after receiving the 1st message) using DefaultMessageListenerConatiner Of Spring (By overriding doReceiveAndExecute) as mentioned in the [link](https://sleeplessinslc.blogspot.com/2010/04/batchmessagelistenercontainer-using.html).

I can group the messages of my batch size i.e 20 when the queue is having too many messages and I can receive less than 20 messages when there are very less messages in Queue.

**Issue :**

I see it takes too much time(sometimes 1 sec and sometime 2 secs and more) for sending the messages to Listener even when the queue is full.

When I try with DefaultMessageListenerConatiner as such to receive single messages concurrently, I see the messages are received in a delay of few milliseconds(like 1 millisec or max 30 to 60 millisec)

I didn't specify transactionTimeout or receiveTimeout and I didn't link any transactionManager as well.

Can Springers please help me  to find where the timeOut can be specified or How can I redeuce the time delay?

**BatchMessageListenerContainer :**

```
package com.mypackage;

import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer;

import org.springframework.jms.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils;
import org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils;
import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionStatus;

/**
 * Listener Container that allows batch consumption of messages. Works only with transacted sessions
 */
public class BatchMessageListenerContainer extends DefaultMessageListenerContainer {
  public static final int DEFAULT_BATCH_SIZE = 20;

  private int batchSize = DEFAULT_BATCH_SIZE;

  public BatchMessageListenerContainer() {
    super();
    setSessionTransacted(true);
  }

  /**
   * @return The batch size on this container
   */
  public int getBatchSize() {
    return batchSize;
  }

  /**
   * @param batchSize The batchSize of this container
   */
  public void setBatchSize(int batchSize) {
    this.batchSize = batchSize;
  }

  /**
   * The doReceiveAndExecute() method has to be overriden to support multiple-message receives.
   */
  @Override
  protected boolean doReceiveAndExecute(Object invoker, Session session, MessageConsumer consumer,
    TransactionStatus status) throws JMSException {

    Connection conToClose = null;
    MessageConsumer consumerToClose = null;
    Session sessionToClose = null;

    try {
      Session sessionToUse = session;
      MessageConsumer consumerToUse = consumer;

      if (sessionToUse == null) {
        Connection conToUse = null;
        if (sharedConnectionEnabled()) {
          conToUse = getSharedConnection();
        }
        else {
          conToUse = createConnection();
          conToClose = conToUse;
          conToUse.start();
        }
        sessionToUse = createSession(conToUse);
        sessionToClose = sessionToUse;
      }

      if (consumerToUse == null) {
        consumerToUse = createListenerConsumer(sessionToUse);
        consumerToClose = consumerToUse;
      }

      List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();

      int count = 0;
      Message message = null;
      // Attempt to receive messages with the consumer
      do {
        message = receiveMessage(consumerToUse);
        if (message != null) {
          messages.add(message);
        }
      }
      // Exit loop if no message was received in the time out specified, or
      // if the max batch size was met
      while ((message != null) && (++count < batchSize));

      if (messages.size() > 0) {
        // Only if messages were collected, notify the listener to consume the same.
        try {
          doExecuteListener(sessionToUse, messages);
          sessionToUse.commit();
        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
          handleListenerException(ex);
          if (ex instanceof JMSException) {
            throw (JMSException) ex;
          }
        }
        return true;
      }

      // No message was received for the period of the timeout, return false.
      noMessageReceived(invoker, sessionToUse);
      return false;
    }
    finally {
      JmsUtils.closeMessageConsumer(consumerToClose);
      JmsUtils.closeSession(sessionToClose);
      ConnectionFactoryUtils.releaseConnection(conToClose, getConnectionFactory(), true);
    }
  }

  protected void doExecuteListener(Session session, List<Message> messages) throws JMSException {
    if (!isAcceptMessagesWhileStopping() && !isRunning()) {
      if (logger.isWarnEnabled()) {
        logger.warn("Rejecting received messages because of the listener container "
          + "having been stopped in the meantime: " + messages);
      }
      rollbackIfNecessary(session);
      throw new JMSException("Rejecting received messages as listener container is stopping");
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    SessionAwareBatchMessageListener<Message> lsnr = (SessionAwareBatchMessageListener<Message>) getMessageListener();

    try {
      lsnr.onMessages(session, messages);
    }
    catch (JMSException ex) {
      rollbackOnExceptionIfNecessary(session, ex);
      throw ex;
    }
    catch (RuntimeException ex) {
      rollbackOnExceptionIfNecessary(session, ex);
      throw ex;
    }
    catch (Error err) {
      rollbackOnExceptionIfNecessary(session, err);
      throw err;
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void checkMessageListener(Object messageListener) {
    if (!(messageListener instanceof SessionAwareBatchMessageListener<?>)) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Message listener needs to be of type ["
        + SessionAwareBatchMessageListener.class.getName() + "]");
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void validateConfiguration() {
    if (batchSize <= 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Property batchSize must be a value greater than 0");
    }
  }

  public void setSessionTransacted(boolean transacted) {
    if (!transacted) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Batch Listener requires a transacted Session");
    }
    super.setSessionTransacted(transacted);
  }
}
```

**SessionAwareBatchMessageListener:**

```
package com.mypackage;

import java.util.List;

import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.Session;

public interface SessionAwareBatchMessageListener<M extends Message> {
  /**
   * Perform a batch action with the provided list of {@code messages}.
   * 
   * @param session JMS {@code Session} that received the messages
   * @param messages List of messages
   * @throws JMSException JMSException thrown if there is an error performing the operation.
   */
  public void onMessages(Session session, List<M> messages) throws JMSException;
}
```

**Bean in applicationContext.xml:**

```
<bean id="myMessageListener" class="org.mypackage.MyMessageListener">

<bean id="jmsContainer" class="com.mypackage.BatchMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    <property name="destinationName" ref="queue"/>
    <property name="messageListener" ref="myMessageListener"/>
    <property name ="concurrentConsumers" value ="10"/>
    <property name ="maxConcurrentConsumers" value ="50"/>        
</bean>
```

MyMessageListner :

```
package org.mypackage;

import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;

import org.mypackage.service.MyService;

public class MyMessageListener implements SessionAwareBatchMessageListener<TextMessage> {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Session session, List<TextMessage> messages) {
        try {
           for(TextMessage tm :messages)  {
                TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
               // parse the message and add to list
            }
            //process list of Objects to DB
        } catch (JMSException e1) {
             e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to say what's wrong when there are enough messages present. Perhaps you don't have a prefetch, and the `receive()` does a round-trip to the broker for each message? When you don't have a full batch available, reducing the `receiveTimeout` should help.

Answer (score 0):

i think that the time spent before sending the message to the consumer was caused by your while loop, because you're awaiting each time the list to be full but this one is only filled by the current thread since it is created inside the doReceiveAndExecute method!

> ```
>   // Exit loop if no message was received in the time out specified, or
>   // if the max batch size was met
>   while ((message != null) && (++count < batchSize));
> ```

maybe this can do it well :

```
...
     List<Message> messages = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Message>());

     @Override
      protected boolean doReceiveAndExecute(Object invoker, Session session, MessageConsumer consumer,
        TransactionStatus status) throws JMSException {

        Connection conToClose = null;
        MessageConsumer consumerToClose = null;
        Session sessionToClose = null;

        try {
          Session sessionToUse = session;
          MessageConsumer consumerToUse = consumer;

          if (sessionToUse == null) {
            Connection conToUse = null;
            if (sharedConnectionEnabled()) {
              conToUse = getSharedConnection();
            }
            else {
              conToUse = createConnection();
              conToClose = conToUse;
              conToUse.start();
            }
            sessionToUse = createSession(conToUse);
            sessionToClose = sessionToUse;
          }

          if (consumerToUse == null) {
            consumerToUse = createListenerConsumer(sessionToUse);
            consumerToClose = consumerToUse;
          }


          Message message = null;
          // Attempt to receive messages with the consumer
          do {
            message = receiveMessage(consumerToUse);
            if (message != null) {
              messages.add(message);
            }
          }

          if (messages.size() >= batchSize)) {
            synchronized (messages) {
              // Only if messages were collected, notify the listener to consume the same.
              try {
                doExecuteListener(sessionToUse, messages);
                sessionToUse.commit();
                // clear the list!!
                messages.clear();
              }
              catch (Throwable ex) {
                handleListenerException(ex);
                if (ex instanceof JMSException) {
                  throw (JMSException) ex;
                }
              }
            }
            return true;
          }

          // No message was received for the period of the timeout, return false.
          noMessageReceived(invoker, sessionToUse);
          return false;
        }
        finally {
          JmsUtils.closeMessageConsumer(consumerToClose);
          JmsUtils.closeSession(sessionToClose);
          ConnectionFactoryUtils.releaseConnection(conToClose, getConnectionFactory(), true);
        }
      }
```

Comment: I will try this and let you know If it works. 1. I think in this way sessionToUse.commit();  can be done by any thread. 2. Any idea which timeout it takes to end?

Comment: The sessionToUse.commit(); is done by the current thread executing the synchronized block, another thread's cannot add messages to the list until the first one finishes and commit. So here is a problem i detect, the commit is only made on the session of the current thread!! Another messages of another thread's sessions will not be committed, you have to use individual acknowledge and commit messages one by one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40399495/activemq-is-it-possible-to-acknowledge-single-message-in-client-acknowledge-mo/40399955#40399955